# How to resolve mongodump error "not recognized"?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Hi feel like this question has an easy answer but I just can't see it.
I am using the command

```
Mongodump --db <name>
```

and i get

```
'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

.
how can i get a backup of my mongodb
thanks

Comment: Hi I used "set path" but when I run the mongodump command it gives me the same error

Answer (score 21):

Starting with MongoDB 4.4, the MongoDB Database Tools are now released separately from the MongoDB Server and use their own versioning, with an initial version of 100.0.0. Previously, these tools were released alongside the MongoDB Server and used matching versioning.

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools

Once database tools contents are put into the bin, set the path and restart your PC.

Answer (score 10):

For windows10, please add the path in the environment variable section.

Firstly, download the mongodb data tools by https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

1. Right click the window start icon => click "system" => click "advanced system setting"
2. Click "environment variable" [image: Systme Properties]
3. **Select** "PATH", click "Edit" , click "New" => Add path which the mongodb data tools is installed
   [image: Environment Varialbe]

For your reference, my path is: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin
[image: Path]

Finally, open the Windows PowerShell:

```
PS C:\>mongodump --version
```

The version of the mongodump should be shown which the setting is ok.

```
mongodump version: 100.5.3 
git version: 139703c0587796da96c367f365473d0266f9cede
Go version: go1.17.8
os: windows
arch: amd64
compiler: gc
```

ref link: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/

Comment: I did all this and still getting the error

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `set path` command first, if you have installed **mongodb**.

```
set path="<mongodb installed directory which contain mongodump file>"
```

[image]

If you don't want to set path every time you open command prompt. then,
[set the path in **environment variables**](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) if you are using windows.